# Making a dll available to all VS projects and have it put into the binary

Tags: visual-studio

I've just found the C5 library for .Net. I would like to 'install' it in a way that I can easily add a reference to it from all my c# projects. I found some information pointing to the global assembly cache. However I'm worried that the binary will only run on my machine. How do I know if VS includes the C5 .dll in my binaries?

Thanks.

EDIT:
Also I have a personal library I use for all my projects. Would it be possible to export the C5 library from inside my own?

Answer (score 0):

I just normally create a solution folder in the root of the solution and add the assemblies there.

This allows you to easily reference them and have them under source control.

Comment: Yeah but then I do have to repeat that action for every project.

Comment: @user93197: You mean for every solution rather?

Answer (score 0):

For a specific project, you could include the DLL in the Visual Studio project and reference it there. The DLL will be checked into source control and will be available to other developers when they check it out. It will also be available to the build server.

If a single DLL must be shared between multiple projects then there are other strategies that involve branching for example. See this [guidance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668956.aspx) from Patterns and Practices for more details.